# Node-persist on heavy Node.js app not returning values

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, node-persist

I have a heavy node app, and I am using node-persist to save data to local db.

On a particular step, I have this:

```
const localdb = require('node-persist')
const storage = localdb.create({ttl: true})
await storage.init()

function game(socket, log, opts) {

   // [...]

    async function scoreHandler(data) {
        if (data.scoreUp) {
            await storage.setItem(data.sid,data.uid)
        } else if (data.scoreDown) {
            try {
                let uid = await storage.getItem(data.sid);

                if (typeof uid == 'undefined') {
                    return;
                }

                console.log(uid);
            } catch (e) {
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This code is a bit deep in a long function. All very simple. But there are two problems:

1. More than often, `uid` is `undefined`. My guess is that the file was not yet saved, so when I try to getItem on that, it has undefined value.
2. <s>Even with that `if (uid == 'undefined')`, `console.log(uid)` still throws many `undefined`. I can't understand why since I am "returning".</s>

The code is really just that. This `if` is probably called 15-20 times per second. There is no other piece of code that may be throwing "undefined" on the console, nor anything writing to the db.

Why is this happening? And what can I do to properly handle it?

**Edit 1**

The point 2 I figured out. I forgot to put `typeof`.

**Edit 2**

I added the `init` as requested.

If I remove the `try...catch`, I get this error quite often:

```
(node:9608) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: [node-persist][readFile] ... does not look like a valid storage file!
    at fs.readFile (...node-persist/src/local-storage.js:277:66)
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:511:3)
```

So, my guess is that `getItem` is trying to read a file that `setItem` has not yet finished to write.

Comment: Can you also post your init call for the node-persists ? Also, if possible add more contextual code, as the issue might not be in this code to start with.

Comment: @Biswanath I added a bit of code and an error message. I think the problem is that I am trying to read a file that the previous setItem has not finished to write.

Comment: It the whole code you show in one function, including the `const storage = localdb.create({ttl: true})` and `await storage.init()`

Comment: @t.niese Sorry, I wanted to keep the code short and simple here and I didn't include the functions declarations. Now there is.

Comment: And that's the only place where you use the `storage`? Could it be that you call `scoreHandler` multible time even so `scoreHandler` is not finished yet? The error message will happen if  `getItem` is called while a `setItem` is in progress. And `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` indicates that you either do not handle the result/expection of `scoreHandler` (or one of the callin ancestors) properly.

Comment: Yes, that is the only place I use `storage`. Yes, `scoreHandler` is called multiple times, maybe 15-20 per second. I see the problem, though I am not sure how to handle it. If you put your comment in an answer, I can accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that `node-persist` does not handle concurrent reads and writes reliable.

If a `getItem` is called while a `setItem` is in progress, then this error will be thrown.

The only solution it either that this is fixed by the library, or that you ensure that you never call `getItem` while a `setItem`.

My suggestion would be to wrap everythign related to that storeage into an own class. So that you can easily replace it later with another library.

I filled an issue:

[Concurrent `setItem` and `getItem` can lead into an unahdled `does not look like a valid storage file`](https://github.com/simonlast/node-persist/issues/108)

Answer (score 2):

To add a bit more to what @t.niese saying, basically there is no concurrency provided by the library. One of the solution would be to serialise the calls to the library. Below is code sample which serialise all the call to the library.

Also, this given the library writes each key value pair to a single file. I think serialising to calls per key would give better throughput.

Having said all this, this should be handled in the library.

comment and uncomment the selection of storage to node-persist or the wrapper around the node-persist.

```
const localdb = require('node-persist')
const when = require('when');


class QueuedStorage  {

  constructor() {
    this.storage = localdb.create({ ttl: true, logging: false})
  }

  async init() {
    await this.storage.init();
  }


  async getItem(key) {
    this.current = when(this.current,
            () => { return this.storage.getItem(key)},
            () => { return this.storage.getItem(key)});
    return this.current;
  }

  async setItem(key, value)  {
    this.current = when(this.current,
            () => { return this.storage.setItem(key,value)},
            () => { return this.storage.setItem(key,value)});
    return this.current;
  }
};


//const storage  = new QueuedStorage();
const storage = localdb.create({ ttl: true, logging: true })


async function main () {
  await storage.init()

  try {
    const key = 'DSF-AS-558-DDDF';
    const fs = new Array(10000)
      .fill(0)
      .map((e,i) => function() {
        if(i%2) return storage.getItem(key)
        else return storage.setItem(key,i)}());

    Promise.all(fs).then(values => console.log(values));

   } catch (err) {
     console.error(err)
   }
}

main().catch(err => {
  console.error(err)
})
```